# How to recursively remove the caret (^) character recursively in all files in a directory?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I wish to remove all caret characters from all files present in the current directory. Please help.

Comment: 1) This way, sed operates on stdin and writes to stdout. To edit files and save back, you need the `-i` flag as well as the file name, which, inside a `find -exec` command, you can get with `{}`. 2) Your command will not simply remove carets, but replace them by commas.

Comment: you may want to add `maxdepth` as well.

Comment: No, that won't work --  it'll do nothing yet it'll never end.

Comment: Can anyone give me an example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must tell `sed` to edit the file in place by specifying the the `-i` option, otherwise `sed` will write to its stdout.
You're not passing any file names to `sed`. Use `{}` syntax of `find` to pass matched file names.

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/\^//g' {} +
```

Please note that to replace matched patterns with nothing, you must leave the replace part of the substitution empty.