# Remove '\r' Character from Files in Directory Recursively

Tags: linux, windows, bash, git

I write code on a Windows 10 machine, upload it to remote Linux machines where it's actually run. Typically using a IDE feature like [Jetbrains upload](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/uploading-and-downloading-files.html#Uploading_and_Downloading_Files-10-procedure) or [WinSCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinSCP). I also do all my version control remotely usually with the following workflow:

```
(in remote session)
 1. $ git clone git@github.com:myorg/myrepo.git
(in local)
 2. Download from remote: /myrepo -> C://User/Me/myrepo
 3. Edit some_file.py
 4. Upload to remote: C://User/Me/myrepo/some_file.py -> /myrepo/some_file.py
(in remote session)
 5. $ python some_file.py  # ERROR: something about bad chars or line endings with '\r'
 6. $ sed -i 's/\r//' some_file.py; python some_file.py  # WORKS!
 7. $ git add some_file.py; git commit -m "removed bad win char"
```

This error and my current method of resolution is rather annoying. I tried automating it with the following bash script I included in my $PATH at ~/mytools/remove_win_char.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/\r//g' {} \;
```

Unfortunately this has some unintended side effects in git repos: (i.e. this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43162721/5289570) does not work)

```
$ remove_win_char.sh
$ git status
fatal: unknown index entry format 0x2f610000
```

I tried to fix by specifying only certain files in the script:

```
find . -name *.py -o -name *.sql -o -name *.sh -exec sed -i 's/\r//g' {} \;
```

Unfortunately this only seems to hit the `.sh` files.

Anyone know how to filter `.py`, `.sql`, and `.sh` files only with `find`? Or know a better way to remove these `\r` characters created locally by Windows?

Comment: Put the filenames with asterisks in single quotes to stop the shell from expanding them: `find . -name '*.py' -o -name '*.sql' ...`

Comment: And quote `'{}'` DOS line-endings and UTF-16 are the best way to ruin a good project `:)` (you may also want to add `-type f` just to ensure no stray directories are picked up.)

Comment: Does `\r` appear anywhere else besides the `\r\n` CRLF characters on Windows? What about strings "\r"? Can these other cases be avoided?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why should I use core.autocrlf=true in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825428/why-should-i-use-core-autocrlf-true-in-git)

Answer (score 3):

Using `find` and `sed` may destroy your repository because they are not aware of the git repository, its internals and the way how git treats tracked files. You have to use [`git ls-files`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files) to produce the list of files it tracks as *text* files with CR/LF line endings and then process the files accordingly:

```sh
git ls-files --eol
```

It produces tabular output like

```
i/lf    w/lf    attr/                   .gitignore
i/crlf  w/crlf  attr/                   README.md
i/lf    w/lf    attr/                   env/install.sh
```

that can be filtered using `awk` (unfortunately, not sure if `grep` can handle fields) and `cut`, and then CR/LF-to-LF-fixed using `dos2unix`.

```sh
git -c core.quotepath=off ls-files --eol '*.py' '*.sql' '*.sh' \ # query git
    | awk '$1 ~ /^i\/crlf/' \                                    # filter only lines starting with i/crlf
    | cut -f2 \                                                  # filter files only (see why it is TAB-delimited https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files#_output)
    | xargs -I{} dos2unix {}                                     # convert CR/LF to LF
```

Comment: @oguzismail thank you for the edit! I didn't even know that `cut` uses TAB as the default delimiter.

Comment: You're welcome. The reason why I didn't upvote this answer is that it doesn't account for files with special characters in their names. Otherwise I totally agree that relying on git itself is a safer approach than relying on dos2unix's heuristic checks.

Comment: @oguzismail Aha, another "didn't know" from my side: I rarely encounter filenames that require octal representation, and mostly saw them in high-level commands like `status` or `show`, so this is why I didn't realize to put that configuration option. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. I tried running the last block on one line in the root of my repo, but my file EOF's still have `w/crlf` and running them produces the usual error: `run.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found`

Comment: @Wassadamo `w/crlf` means that you have CR/LF-lined files in your working copy (not yet staged with `git add`), whilst the script above filters for indexed files only (can be modified of course). Also, I'm not really sure what does "the last block" mean. Could you elaborate please?